# mysql 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, mysql-workbench

I have created the schema with Workbench 6.1 (and MySQL 5.6) and it outputs the code below. But this produces a foreign key constraint. Last time it worked but produced a composite primary key made of the other foreign keys which is overkill I think.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `yii_jobmedisearch` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yii_jobmedisearch`.`Person` (
  `PersId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Vorname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `MiddleName` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `Nachname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `Anrede` ENUM('Herr','Frau','Herr Dr.','Frau Dr.','Herr Prof.','Frau Prof.') NOT NULL,
  `Titel` ENUM('Dr.','Prof.') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Geschlecht` ENUM('Frau','Mann','Transident') NOT NULL,
  `Geburtsdatum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Nationalitaet` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,`enter code here`
  `Nationalitaet2` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Heimatort` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Strasse` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLZ` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Wohnort` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `Kanton` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `TelHome` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `TelMobil` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zivilstand` ENUM('ledig','verheiratet','geschieden','verwittwet') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `SkypeId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FacebookId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `GooglePlusId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `XingId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkedInId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `TwitterId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `IstSuchend` ENUM('Sucht','Sucht nicht') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AbsenzVon` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AbsenzBis` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PersonCreateDatum` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `PersonModifDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yii_jobmedisearch`.`User` (
  `UserId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `UserPass` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `UserRolle` ENUM('guest','AGeber','ANehmer','ProAGeber','ProAGeberAdmin','ProANehmer','ProVermittler','ProVermittlerAdmin','Maintainer','Admin') NOT NULL,
  `Person_PersId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `JobFirma_JobId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Filiale_FilialeId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `UserCreateDatum` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UserModifDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UserVerified` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`),
  INDEX `fk_User_Person_idx` (`Person_PersId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_User_Filiale1_idx` (`Filiale_FilialeId` ASC, `Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UserName_UNIQUE` (`UserName` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Person`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Person_PersId`)
    REFERENCES `yii_jobmedisearch`.`Person` (`PersId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_User_Filiale1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Filiale_FilialeId` , `Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    REFERENCES `yii_jobmedisearch`.`Filiale` (`FilialeId` , `HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yii_jobmedisearch`.`HQFirma` (
  `HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HQFirmenname` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `HQAnzFilialen` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQGesellschaftsform` ENUM('AG','GmbH','Einzelfirma') NOT NULL,
  `HQBranche` ENUM('Spital','Klinik','Stellenvermittler','Versicherung') NOT NULL,
  `HQFirmenbeschrieb` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
  `HQStrasse` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `HQPLZ` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `HQPostfach` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQOrt` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `HQFax` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQTelefon` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `HQTelefon2` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQEmail` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `HQEmail2` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQWebURL` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQWebURL2` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQAnzLikes` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQSkypeId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQFacebookId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQGooglePlusId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQXingId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQLinkedInId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQTwitterId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQFirmaCreateDatum` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `HQFirmaModifDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`HQFirmaId`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `HQFirmenname_UNIQUE` (`HQFirmenname` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yii_jobmedisearch`.`Filiale` (
  `FilialeId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Strasse` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `Postfach` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLZ` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Ort` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `Fax` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Telefon` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `Telefon2` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `Email2` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `WebURL` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `WebURL2` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `SkypeId` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `FacebookId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `GooglePlusId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `XingId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkedInId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `TwitterId` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnzLikes` MEDIUMINT(9) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `FilialeName` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `FilialeCreateDatum` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `FilialeModifDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FilialeId`),
  INDEX `fk_Filiale_HQFirma1_idx` (`HQFirma_HQFirmaId` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `FilialenName_UNIQUE` (`FilialeName` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Filiale_HQFirma1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    REFERENCES `yii_jobmedisearch`.`HQFirma` (`HQFirmaId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yii_jobmedisearch`.`Promotions` (
  `PromoId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PromoTyp` ENUM('TopList','Highlighting') NOT NULL,
  `PromoBeginn` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PromoEnd` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobFirma_JobId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_UserId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_Person_PersId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_JobId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PromoCreationDatum` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `PromoModifDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PromoId`),
  INDEX `fk_Promotions_JobFirma1_idx` (`JobFirma_JobId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Promotions_User1_idx` (`User_UserId` ASC, `User_Person_PersId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_JobId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Promotions_JobFirma1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`JobFirma_JobId`)
    REFERENCES `yii_jobmedisearch`.`JobFirma` (`JobId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Promotions_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`User_UserId` , `User_Person_PersId` , `User_JobFirma_JobId` , `User_JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` , `User_JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` , `User_JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    REFERENCES `yii_jobmedisearch`.`User` (`UserId` , `Person_PersId` , `JobFirma_JobId` , `JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` , `JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` , `JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yii_jobmedisearch`.`JobFirma` (
  `JobId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `JobCreateDatum` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `JobModifDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `JobPostDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `JobBeginnDatum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `JobExpireDatum` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `JobTitel` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `JobBranche` ENUM('Spital','Stellenvermittler','Klinik','Versicherung') NOT NULL,
  `JobSynopsis` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnforderungen` VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
  `JobDescription` VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL,
  `JobAngebot` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobEduLevel` ENUM('PhD','Master','Lehre','Berufserfahrung') NOT NULL,
  `JobEduLevel2` ENUM('PhD','Master','Lehre','Berufserfahrung') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobEduLevel3` ENUM('PhD','Master','Lehre','Berufserfahrung') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAgeRange` ENUM('18-25','25-35','35-45','45-65','egal') NOT NULL,
  `JobNationalitaet` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `JobPlace` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `JobTimeModel` ENUM('Teilzeit','Vollzeit','auf Abruf') NOT NULL,
  `JobTimePercent` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `JobContractModel` ENUM('Permanent','Temporär','Freelancer') NOT NULL,
  `JobAnzViews` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnzBewerbungen` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnzStars` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnz1Star` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnz2Star` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnz3Star` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnz4Star` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnz5Star` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobAnz6Star` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobStars` FLOAT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobWebURL` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `JobWebPDF` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Filiale_FilialeId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_UserId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_Person_PersId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_JobId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `User_JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JobId`),
  INDEX `fk_JobFirma_Filiale1_idx` (`Filiale_FilialeId` ASC, `Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_JobFirma_User1_idx` (`User_UserId` ASC, `User_Person_PersId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_JobId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` ASC, `User_JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JobFirma_Filiale1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Filiale_FilialeId` , `Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    REFERENCES `yii_jobmedisearch`.`Filiale` (`FilialeId` , `HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JobFirma_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`User_UserId` , `User_Person_PersId` , `User_JobFirma_JobId` , `User_JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` , `User_JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` , `User_JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    REFERENCES `yii_jobmedisearch`.`User` (`UserId` , `Person_PersId` , `JobFirma_JobId` , `JobFirma_HQFirma_HQFirmaId` , `JobFirma_Filiale_FilialeId` , `JobFirma_Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
COMMENT =  /* comment truncated */ /*   */;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

---

### LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR

```
2014-04-07 15:16:31 ce0 Error in foreign key constraint of table yii_jobmedisearch/user:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:
,
 CONSTRAINT "fk_User_Filiale1" FOREIGN KEY ("Filiale_FilialeId", "Filiale_HQFirma_HQFirmaId") REFERENCES "filiale" ("FilialeId", "HQFirma_HQFirmaId") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
The index in the foreign key in table is "fk_User_Filiale1_idx"

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition.
```

Comment: You need to order your tables such that referenced tables are created before those which reference them. I see that `Filiale` does not yet exist when `User` attempts to reference it via FK.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I corrected the order some more, but that didn't help in this error.